# Departure airport in moscow has changed during transit flight

Tags: transit, airports, aeroflot

So i'm traveling from tokyo to paris with a transition in Moscow, on August 14-15.
I've just learned through an audio message that the departure airport for the moscow=>paris route had changed, meaning that i'm supposed to change airport in Moscow. I'm french and don't have a Russian Visa.
I've called the booking website (mytrip.com) but they don't have any informations regarding this. I've written to aeroflot but they haven't answer yet.

Do i need a Russian transit visa or similar ? Can I expect to switch to another Moscow =>Paris flight from Aeroflot on the same day ? What are my options here ?

For precisions :
Tokyo => Moscow: Flight, SU 261, arriving at Moscow Sheremetyevo WED 14 AUG 16:05
Moscow => Paris : Flight SU 6637, departing from Moscow  THU 15 AUG 10:50

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, [Flight 6637 departs from Sheremetyevo Airport as well.](https://www.rossiya-airlines.com/en/flight-with-us/before_flight/timetable_flight/?depart_city=SVO&arrival_city=ORY&direction=O&DATE=15.08.2019)  Are you sure you have to change airports?

Comment: Check that message again and be sure to distinguish whether they changed the departing AIRPORT or if it's just a change in TERMINAL (more likely)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems after listening several times to the message that it is indeed a change of terminal rather than change in airport. sorry for the inconvenience. The robot voice speaking english with a russian english was too much for my french ears :D

Comment: I suggest that you delete the question, as it's based on a mistake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was apparently written in error